# How to postgres search with two search text parameter, Search FIlter text 1 && search filter text 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pg-search

How to Postgres search with two search text parameter ,  pg-search + Search FIlter 1 + search filter 2 .

How to search in [pg_Search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search)  output I want union of  "filter 1" && "filter 1"

```
 @output = PgSearch.multisearch("filter 1") +  PgSearch.multisearch("filter 2")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author and maintainer of pg_search.

Search terms are joined by AND by default in PostgreSQL full text search. Thus, you could simply do this:

```
 @output = PgSearch.multisearch("filter 1 filter 2")
```

Assuming you have the query terms in string variables, it would look something like one of these:

```
 @output = PgSearch.multisearch("#{query1} #{query2}") # if query1 and query2 are strings
 @output = PgSearch.multisearch(queries.join(" "))     # if queries is an array of strings
```

Joining by OR is a lot more complicated. I don't yet have an easy solution for it, although it should be possible.